# Regex: Only numbers or empty string

Tags: regex

I have a telephone input field. You should only type numbers, spaces or leave it empty.
An idea how to build the regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex would be

```
^[\d ]*$      # in JavaScript, that's /^[\d ]*$/
```

but I would not do it this way. You should allow all characters, then filter out the numbers in a second step, using something like `result = subject.replace(/\D+/g, "");`.

Reason: People have all kinds of ways to enter phone numbers (`1-(123) 343-2345` etc.), and they don't like it if a website tells them the number is incorrect.

Are you aware that you're excluding country codes with this requirement? I have all my phone numbers stored as `+49 123 456-7890`, and I wouldn't like my country code to be mistaken for an area code.

Comment: My requirements are determined: The field should only accept phone numbers like this: 033 333 33 33

Comment: OK, but I guess you should still do a sanity check afterwards (inputs like `"1"` or `"  0  "` would be valid, too...)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[\d\s]*$/
```